# Pusher: JSON возвращаемый с auth endpoint пустая строка

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo

Я хочу делать уведомления в реальном времени используя Pusher, Vue и Laravel Echo. В файле Vue подключаюсь к private channel, но JSON, который возвращается с auth endpoint пустая строка, а должен быть auth token настолько я помню и из-за этого error, делал точно такое несколько месяцев назад, сравниваю с прошлым проектом, вроде ошибок нет.

Сделал кастомный guard - teacher, для учителей (нужно для проекта)

**config/auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'teacher' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'teacher',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'teacher' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Teacher::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**resources/js/bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,    
});

Pusher.logToConsole = true; // включаю log-и pusher а
```

**Vue файл, подключаюсь к private channel в функции mounted**

```
mounted(){
        window.Echo.private('homeworknotif')
        .listen('HomeworkAdded', e => {
          console.log(e);
        })
      },
```

**HomeworkAdded event файл**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class HomeworkAdded implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $message;
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('homeworknotif');
    }
}
```

**routes/channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('homeworknotif', function($user, $id){
    return true;
});
```

**в controller файле вызываю broadcast**

```
public function eventer(){
        broadcast(new HomeworkAdded('hello world'));
    }
```

Когда меняю Vue файл с `window.Echo.private` на `window.Echo.channel`, то ошибок нет, в консоле как Pusher log выводятся данные, которые я отправляю, но если удаляю `Pusher.logToConsole = true;`, данные не выводятся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась. Я просто не изменил BROADCAST_DRIVER в файле .env.